# How does "keydown" know to automatically pass an argument to a Function?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The following code works perfect.

If the `ESC` key is pressed `function` closeModal fires.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { if (e.keyCode == "27") { closeModal(); }} );
```

I must be missing an important piece of knowledge because from a technical standpoint I'm not sure how/why `keydown` knows to create and then send the `e` argument to the function.  How does `keydown` know to send `e` anywhere at all?

As a comparison in this code that uses `click` no argument is sent or asked for.  I know the function isn't written to accept an argument but I don't think `click` creates or sends an argument anyway.  And if it did how would it know to get to the function sitting next to it?  Maybe I'm wrong about all of this.

```
document.getElementById("portfolio-large").addEventListener("click", closeModal);
```

Comment: The browser always sends the event object to event listeners. Some event listeners actually use it, other don't.

Comment: @jcaron Fascinating!  I used the console log to look at the argument `e` and it came back with like 20 properties.  I'm going to check that on every event.  Awesome!

Comment: @DR01D Yeah man, `event.target` can come in handy for a lot of things. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is created by the browser.

So when you attach a listener to the window object and that event fires, the browser creates the event and passes it to your function. It will work with any event driven action including click.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

Everything is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener)

Basically you are attaching callback function which is then called upon event with event itself as an argument.

You are wrong about `click` listener - it also receives an `event` argument.